# Angular CORS Request Not Being Submitted

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors

I am using Angular 4; My current browser is Google Chrome with CORS enabled. I am trying to make CORS call but nothing happens and no error message is displayed. Here is my service code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class FlowLoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  private getTokenURL = 'http://targeturl.com/api/login';  // URL to web api

  login(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log("executing login");
    return this.http
      .post(this.getTokenURL, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {console.log(res); res.json().data as any})
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

Logging something before the return statement within the login method prove that the method is executed. However the promise is never returned, a look at the server log shows that it didn't receive any request, no error is caught by the catch statement and the browser dev console doesn't mention that a CORS request has been attempted.
My assumption is since I am running the dev server the request is submitted to 'http://localhost:4200/http://targeturl.com/api/login'.
What changes needs to be made for the request to succesfully be submitted to 'http://targeturl.com/api/login'.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the client (browser). Chrome won't make the request if the server fails to return certain headers. This is a good place to start: [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Enabling CORS in the server didn't solve the issue. I am still seeing the same behavior; I don't think the question should be categorized as not useful as long as it is not proven that  enabling CORS on the server is the solution. Also why voting down the question when my description clearly shows that I took time to try to identify where the issue happens and find out plausible causes? Yes my assumption was wrong, but I clearly made efforts so why voting down...

Comment: Your browsers console should show that an OPTIONS request was made if Angular is correctly configured to use CORS.  I'm not familiar with Angular 4, so I can't tell you how you would do that.  If your browser isn't sending *any* requests, this isn't a CORS issue at all.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is configured properly? Try issuing a simple request from your browser console and see what happens. Also, I did not vote down your question, I find it to be just fine.

Comment: Your question is fine to me.  I dunno why you received a downvote.  I wouldn't worry about it though.

Comment: I apologize for the mini-rant then.

Comment: CORS are enabled, I checked again. I had the same issue with Angular2... I will keep looking...